# Why Use Spring's Dependency Injection Over Regular Dependency Injection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I'm just learning Spring coming from a Java background. What I understand dependency injection to be is that
you supply the objects it's dependencies, rather than the object initializing its own dependencies. For example:

```java
/*
   MyObj depends on HashMap as a dependency.
 */
public class MyObj {
  private HashMap hashmap;

  public MyObj() {
    this.hashmap = new HashMap();
  }
}
```

Instead of doing that, you supply the `HashMap` through the constructor.

```java
/*
   MyObj depeneds on HashMap as a dependency.
 */
public class MyObj {
  private HashMap hashmap;

  public MyObj(HashMap hashmap) {
    this.hashmap = hashmap;
  }
}
```

This is what I think dependency injection to be. But the way Spring does it is, in my opinion, more code
and just messier. In Spring, you have to have this separate method

```java
@Bean
public HashMap hashmap() {
  return new HashMap();
}
```

Then construct the `MyObj` object using `ApplicationContext.getBean(MyObj.class)`. However, I find many problems
with this method. First of all, in a Swing app, this is how I would initialze the component ui tree maker:

```java
public class ComponentUI {
  public ComponentUI(JFrame frame, JPanel panel, ...) {
    this.frame = frame;
    this.panel = panel;
    ...
  }
}
```

There are going to be many many components in that constructor. This way, I can construct `ComponentUI` by
doing `new ComponentUI(...)` and pass in the components. With Spring, however, I have to have a separate
method for each one. That takes a lot of space and a lot of time to make each method. But the problem
I find even worse is that if there are two `JPanel`'s in the constructor, then you have to create two
separate objects that extend `JPanel`. Let me show you what I mean:

```java
public class ComponentUI {
  public ComponentUI(..., JPanel panel1, JPanel panel2, ...) {
    ...
    this.panel1 = panel1;
    this.panel2 = panel2;
    ...
  }
}
```

With Spring, I can't do this:

```java
@Bean
public JPanel panel1() {
  ...
}

@Bean
public JPanel panel2() {
  ...
}
```

or else there will be two methods returning the same object, so Spring doesn't know which one to use.
Instead, I have to create my own objects that derive from `JPanel` then use that everywhere. In my
Swing app, I have a whole folder of components that derive from other components.

So with these inconveniences in mind, why would I use Spring's dependency injection over regular dependency
injection, which is, constructing the object and supplying the objects.

Comment: Those are all very bad examples of dependency injection. For one, you wouldn't use dependency injection just to initialize a `HashMap`. Perhaps if you read through a few *tutorials* on Spring, and see the examples they use, you'd get a better understanding on what Spring dependency injection is used for.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah I guess `HashMap` is a pretty bad example, it's just that for some reason that was the first thing that popped in my head.

Answer (score 1):

Spring dependency injection does more then what you are showing. When you try to do everything by yourself with real world problem, you will see the pain and then will appreciate the benefits of Spring dependency and i bet you will start using spring in no time.

I am not saying you have to use spring DI but it would make your life easier.